# What is wrong with my remove method for certain array integers?

Tags: java

I have to create a method that will remove at certain value from an array and create a new array without that certain value. For example, if my array is (0,2,3,5,3) and I want to remove 3, the new array should be (0,2,5). For some reason, it only works for the first two digits.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class removeDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //array of numbers
        int array[] = new int[] {0,1,2,3,4,5};
        //invokes method and prints result
        //System.out.println(remove(3,array));
        remove(3,array);


    }
    //method remove that removes selected number from array
    public static int[] remove(int v, int[] in) {
        //count variable counts how many non-target numbers
        int count = 0;
        //for loop that checks if value at certain index is not equal to "v", the target number for removal
        for(int k = 0; k < in.length; k++) {
            //checks if certain number at certain index of array is not equal to v, or in this case, 3

            if(in[k] != v) {
                //counter
                count++;

            }
    }

        //new array that will stores values except "v"
        int copy[] = new int[count];
        //prints the length
        System.out.println("array length: " + copy.length);
        //for loop that checks if number not 3
        for(int a = 1; a < in.length;) {
        //  sets number at certain index of main array into new array
            if(in[a] != 3){
                copy[a] = in[a];
                a++;

                System.out.println(copy[0]);
                System.out.println(copy[1]);
                System.out.println(copy[2]);
                System.out.println(copy[3]);


            }
            else if(in[a] == 3) {

                copy[a] = in[a+1];
            }


        }

        //returns new array
        return copy;
}

}
```

As said before, I need the new array to exclude the targeted number for removal.

Comment: `System.out.println(remove(3,array));` wouldn't print the result (usefully). `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(remove(3,array)));` would.

Comment: Note that `in[a] != 3` (and `==`) should probably use `v` rather than 3.

Comment: are you allowed to use the stream api ?

Comment: why are you starting at int a =1 ? it should probably be 0

Comment: if you are allowed to use the stream api ?
=> Arrays.stream(in).filter(e->e!=v).toArray(int[]::new)

Comment: why just dont use google?
http://www.java67.com/2016/01/how-to-remove-numbers-from-array-in-java-example.html

Answer (score 0):

You need two index variables for making the copy: one runs through the input array (`a`, as in the original code), and the other tracks your position in the output array (`b`, new variable). They can not be calculated from each other (they are the same at the beginning, but `b` can be significantly less than `a` at the end)

```
int b = 0;
for(int a = 0; a < in.length; a++) {
  if(in[a] != v) {
    copy[b] = in[a];
    b++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result with some code like this:

```
// Add to params all inputs to remove from array
List<Integer> params = new ArrayList<>();

// Use Integer class instead of int datatype
Integer array[] = new Integer[] {0,1,2,3,4,3};

// Convert array to List class
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));

// Remove all matches
list.removeAll(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java8 and it's streams feature you could do something like :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 int[] array = {3236,47,34,34,73,46,3,64,473,4,4,346,4,63,644,4,6,4};
 int[] newArray = removeAllOccurencesOf(array, 4);
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
 }


 public static int[] removeAllOccurencesOf(int[] array, int numberToRemove)
 {
 //stream integers from array, filter the ones that correspond to number to remove, get what's left to new array
 int[] newArray = IntStream.of(array).filter(i->i!=numberToRemove).toArray();
 return newArray;
 }
```